# Parallel.Foreach with ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync function is not improving the performance(Asp.net core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, azure-table-storage

Fetching records from Azure table with different criteria condition need to be executed 10 times. I am using `Parallel.Foreach` method to execute the `ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync` in parallel. But with or without `Parallel.Foreach`, the code execution time is the same.

### Below is the sample code I am using:

```
List<T> result = new List<T>();

var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

Parallel.ForEach(List, (item) => // source collection
{
  var temp = filter(pos, item.no, table, from, till);
  if (temp != null) { result.AddRange(temp); }
});
stopWatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("thread", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

public List<T> filterByTail(List<string> engPos, string tail, CloudTable table, string filterFromDate, string filterTillDate)
    {
        try
        { do
            {
                var queryResult = table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(rangeQuery, token, null, null).Result;
                dataset.AddRange(queryResult.Results);
                token = queryResult.ContinuationToken;
            }
            while (token != null);
return dataset;
}}
```

---

How to improve the performance of fetching data from Azure using parallel processing?

Comment: Please post all of the relevant code

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking out this external blog: https://martincarlsen.com/boost-your-azure-table-storage-performance/ 
The author discusses increasing performance using parallelism, which you have mentioned. He uses a combination of batch and ExecuteBatchAsync for better performance processing. 
[image]

Comment: I have tried implementing the steps which is mentioned in the blog.But unable to get any performance improvement.